# PySpark: Create Dataframe Dynamically from Nested Arrays using Array Values as Column Headers

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, pyspark

I am faced with a problem hope someone can help.

Suppose I have incoming data stream with records looking like this:

{ "headers":["col_a", "col_b", "col_c", "col_d"], "data":[["0","1","2","3"], ["0.2","0.1","3","4"],["5","4","3","2"]]}

{ "headers":["col_a", "col_b", "col_c", "col_d"], "data":[["0.1","1.2","2.5","3"], ["0","0","1","0"]]}

...

Now further suppose that the data is cleaned such that:

1. The "headers" field always contain the same array
2. The arrays within the "data" array are always the same length as the headers array

Is there anyway to turn the above records into a dataframe like below in PySpark?

| col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 0.2 | 0.1 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 0.1 | 1.2 | 2.5 | 3 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Would greatly appreciate any comments and/or working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I found 2 ways of doing this

1. Use a map
2. Use a pivot operation - For this you need to be able to collect all the data into a single partition on the grouping operation. So it will fail on large datasets

#### Map solution

```
  df = spark.read.json("map.json")
  
  # collect the headers as a list
  headers = df.select(F.explode("headers").alias("headers")).distinct().collect()
  headers = [r.headers for r in headers]
  
  # explode data arrays so that it has the same dimensions as the header array
  df = df.select(F.explode("data").alias("data"), "headers")
  # zip data and headers together to form a map
  df = df.select(F.arrays_zip("headers", "data").alias("map"))
  df = df.select(F.map_from_entries("map").alias("map"))
  
  #select out your headers from the map to form columns
  df = df.select(*[df.map.getItem(col).alias(col) for col in headers])
  df.show(truncate=False)
  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
  |col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
  |0    |1    |2    |3    |
  |0.2  |0.1  |3    |4    |
  |5    |4    |3    |2    |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

#### Pivot solution

```
  df = spark.read.json("map.json")

  # explode data arrays so that it has the same dimensions as the header array
  df = df.select(F.explode("data").alias("data"), "headers")
  # zip data and headers together and explode it into rows
  df = df.select(F.arrays_zip("headers", "data").alias("zipped"))
  df = df.select(F.explode("zipped").alias("exploded_struct"))
  df = df.selectExpr("exploded_struct.*")
  
  # Add a single index so that we can group by it and then pivot our headers into columns. 
  # **NB This groups all of our data into a single partition
  df = df.withColumn("idx", F.lit(1))
  df = df.groupBy("idx").pivot("headers").agg(F.collect_list("data").alias("data")).drop("idx")
  
  # each column now contains it's array of data. in order to explode it we need to zip all of them 
  # together and explode in a single operation
  df = df.withColumn("zipped",F.arrays_zip(*df.columns))
  df = df.select(F.explode("zipped").alias("exploded_struct"))
  
  # Finally we select out our headers from the exploded_struct
  df = df.selectExpr("exploded_struct.*")
  df.show(truncate=False)

 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+
   |col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+
   |0    |1    |2    |3    |
   |0.2  |0.1  |3    |4    |
   |5    |4    |3    |2    |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the timely and detailed solution. They worked for me very well!

Comment: @dfzr123 glad to help. Please upvote my answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: I would like to, but I'm new to Stack Overflow and don't have enough reputation to upvote >_< ...will do that as soon as I can..

Comment: Ahhh sorry, I thought you only needed 10 rep to vote, but now I see it's 15.